# Generating functions question

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

How to transform $\sum_{n=2}^\infty n^2x^n$ to $\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^n$

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)= \sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} n^{2}x^{n}$ and $g(x)= \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} nx^{n}$ then $g(x)=nx+ \int_0^x \frac {f(t)} t dt$.

Comment: The question is very ambiguous... but the (correct) way you answer should be less allusive by giving names $f(x)=...$, $g(x)=...$,and writing it $g(x)=\int \dfrac{f(x)}{x}dx$